# Page focus in QtabWidget(pyQT)

Tags: qt, focus, pyqt, qtabwidget

May be this question appears to be realy basic thing, but i am not able to find the solution to the issue.

I want to load the elements of the page(QWidget) in tab layout as i click on it.
I changed the focus policy to click focus of the Qwidget(of page) inside the tab widget.

Now, i m stuck with which focus command or method should i use load the elements of the page. I tried hasFocus or setFocus, but its not working, can be because i am not able to it in a right way.

Also, how can i check if the focus is received by that particular page. 
I tried adding the command(self.twTest.hasFocus()) at the time of initializing the app, but it only checks in the starting of the app.

Thanks

Comment: I really don't understand your question. Could you please post some code and explain what you are after?

Comment: i just want to register the focus of the clicked page in the tabWidget, i am not able to do that.

Comment: What does 'registering the focus' mean?

Comment: Suppose i have 3 tab pages, i want perform some action(basically, load the contents) if first page gets the focus

Comment: Doesn't `currentChanged` signal of the `QTabWidget` do what you want?

Comment: @  Avaris ..it worked. I didn't knew the currentChanged signal
thanks